# Getting black screen while opening PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. And I am trying to install **PostegreSQL** with **WAMP**. And I followed  [here](http://toolkt.com/site/install-postgresql-and-phppgadmin-in-windows-with-wamp/)

I downloaded WampServer, PostgreSQL, phpPgAdmin.

1. First, install the PostgreSQL. It is a simple installation procedure. Just click Next Until, when you come to the screen where you give the installation directory. Make it to your suitable directory
2. Then in the next screen you will be prompted with the Port number. Make sure it does not conflict with the MySQL port 3306. So I used the default as 5432.
3. Next click on Finish. And we are done with the installations.
4. Check installation of PostgreSQL by clicking Start ->Programs ->PostgreSQL 9.1 ->PgAdmin III.
5. Click on Server(1) and Right Click on PostgreSQL Database Server 9.1 (localhost:5432) and Select Connect to obtain a connection to server and give password. It will connect to Database server.

   I created phppgadmin.cfg

   Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.0.2/"

   ```
   <Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.0.2/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride all
           Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```

   And I tried to `http://localhost/phppgadmin/` it shows 403 error

   I Installled and Set the stack Builder for PostgreSQL.And after that i Can't do this step:

Check installation of PostgreSQL by clicking Start ->Programs ->PostgreSQL 9.1 ->PgAdmin IV.

Comment: Please add more details about what went wrong - do you get an error?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and add exactly what you've tried and what you are seeing. Any logs/errors may also help. Your current description is not full enough so that others can help you.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: is your WAMP installation in `C:/wamp/` or is it `C:/wamp64/` check your paths and make sure they are exact.